Plane bestfit only gives parabola over scatterplot?
I have plotted a bunch of data as a scatter plot on 3 axes.
I used one way and got a parabola shape, which wasn't what I wanted, but the example given shows a distinct plane shape.  I guess I am confused/don't know enough to properly diagnose what my issue is, because looking up and changing the equation only breaks the notebook.
temp and x,y,z in the code below is basically the data.
def func(xy, a, b, c, d, e, f): 
    x, y = xy 
    return a + b*x + c*y + d*x**2 + e*y**2 + f*x*y

x = temp[xStr].to_numpy()
y = temp[yStr].to_numpy()
z = temp[zStr].to_numpy()

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (x, y), z) 

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 

ax.set_xlim(0.15, 0.55)
ax.set_ylim(0, 35)
ax.set_zlim(60, 95)


x_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 50) 
y_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range) 
Z = func((X, Y), *popt) 

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='red', alpha=1) 
 

my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('cool')
 

sctt = ax.scatter3D(x, y, z,
                    alpha = 0.8,
                    c = (z), 
                    cmap = my_cmap, 
                    marker ='^')
 
plt.title("Line " + str(arg1))
ax.set_xlabel('Head CU', fontweight ='bold') 
ax.set_ylabel('ASCU', fontweight ='bold') 
ax.set_zlabel('Recovery', fontweight ='bold')
fig.colorbar(sctt, ax = ax, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)

And when this plots, I get a very obvious red parabola. How would I get a plane?


The equation of a plane does not include quadratic terms like x^2, y^2 and xy, as you have in your func. At the moment this is fitting a paraboloid. z=ax+by+c would be better here.

So I changed it to z = ax+by+c, but it is now just giving a line and not a plane. That's a hint but I'm thinking there is something fundamental I don't know with how popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (x, y), z)  works?

There are two main things wrong with your code.
Firstly, the equation of a plane should be linear in x and y (as already noted in a comment). You simply need
def func(xy, a, b, c): 
    x, y = xy 
    return a + b*x + c*y

Secondly, the surface that you plot, whether paraboloid or plane, is only for ranges
x_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 50) 
y_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)

The y_range of 0-1, in particular, bears no resemblance to the limits that you have set in your plot for y limits, i.e. 0-35. Thus you ARE plotting a surface, but it simply looks more like a line because it is only covering about 3% of the y range in your plot.
I have made up some data in the modified code below (because you didn't supply it). The plane is clearly fitted. You can get a, b, c printed out from the values in popt and they match what was supplied in (my) test data.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def func(xy, a, b, c): 
    x, y = xy 
    return a + b*x + c*y

x = np.array( [ 0.2, 0.25, 0.20, 0.3, 0.30, 0.35, 0.45, 0.50, 0.50 ] )
y = np.array( [ 2.0, 20.0, 30.0, 3.0, 30.0, 35.0, 15.0, 18.0, 20.0 ] )
z = 60 + 15 * x + 0.6 * y

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (x, y), z)
print( "a, b, c=", popt ) 

xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax = 0.15, 0.55, 0.0, 35.0, 60.0, 95.0
x_range = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 50)
y_range = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range) 
Z = func((X,Y), *popt)


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 
ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
ax.set_zlim(zmin,zmax)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='red', alpha=0.2)
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('cool')
sctt = ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, alpha=0.8, c=(z), cmap=my_cmap, marker='^')
ax.set_xlabel('Head CU', fontweight ='bold') 
ax.set_ylabel('ASCU', fontweight ='bold') 
ax.set_zlabel('Recovery', fontweight ='bold')
fig.colorbar(sctt, ax = ax, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)
plt.show()


